# Count number of bits to be flipped to convert A to B

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators, hamming-distance

Suppose, I have two numbers A and B. I need to find out how many numbers of bits needed to be changed to convert A to B.

Like:

```
A = 1101101
B = 1011011
     ^^ ^^
```

Here, we need to change 4 bits to convert A to B

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```
int need=__builtin_popcountll(A^B);
cout<<need;
```

Comment: if A and B are `int`s, `__builtin_popcount` is enough

Comment: Also note that it depends on the compiler. Those are for [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). For example on MSVC you need [`__popcnt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231.aspx). For others have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)

Comment: @AliAkber, This is simplest. tnx

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution:

```
A = 1101101
B = 1011011
     ^^ ^^
C = 0110110 (A ^ B)
     ^^ ^^  (count set bit)
```